# How do I call an AngularJS service function inside a Redux Reducer?

Tags: angularjs, redux

I need to call a angularjs function inside a Redux Reducer.
How should I do that?

The Reducer is written in node fasion:
`module.exports = ...`

But the Angular Js factories or services are only accessible with Angularjs Injection.

How should I access those within the Redux reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get an AngularJS injector:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
```

### OR

```
var injector = angular.element(element);
```

For more inforation, see

- [AngularJS angular.injector Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)
- [AngularJS angular.element Function API Reference - jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)